# How can I use 2 different font for different line in one cell after using CONCATENATE in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Qoll.jpg)

Is there any way to change the  font of specific line within an excel cell?

Answer (score 1):

You can figure out the character position of where the second line starts (perhaps using [`LEN`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/len-function) on the first string before concatenation) and then use the [**`Characters.Font`** property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/excel-vba/articles/characters-font-property-excel) to set the [**`color`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/excel-vba/articles/font-color-property-excel) of the appropriate characters.

---

### More Information:

- MSDN : [**`Len` Function** (Excel/VBA)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/len-function)
- MSDN : [**`Characters.Font` Property** (Excel/VBA)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/excel-vba/articles/characters-font-property-excel)
- MSDN : [**`Font.Color` Property** (Excel/VBA)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/excel-vba/articles/font-color-property-excel)
- FunctionX : [**Cell Formatting With Font**](http://www.functionx.com/vbaexcel/cells/Lesson2.htm)
  -

Comment: can you do it for me please i don't know that codding ?

Comment: All the information you need has been provided in this answer, this isn't a code for me site.